# How to get a reference to google Map object from the id of the container?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is possible to get a reference to the google.maps.Map object for a given DOM element?

Comment: Shouldn't you put all javascript together, so you could access your local Map variable from a javascript in the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get an already instantiated map given a DOM element.

I usually work around in one of two ways, created a global map variable or passing the map variable around between functions as needed.  If you're working with multiple maps on a page, you could probably create your own map registry that handled simple DOM id -> map variable lookups.